# Is it possible to debug PHP files on VirtualBox/Ubuntu by mounting them via sshfs onto WSL/Ubuntu and using VSCode/WSL target on local/Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtualbox, xdebug

Nginx is running on Ubuntu in VirtualBox, and the project root is mounted using sshfs on WSL/Ubuntu.

Editing is done using VSCode's WSL target. (`192.168.56.2` is the address of Ubuntu on VirtualBox, using host-only adapter.)

```
# in wsl
sshfs user@192.168.56.2:/nginx ~/mountpoint
```

I usually only work with JS, but now I need to edit PHP.

I've made the following settings, but I can't debug it. (`192.168.56.1` is the host-side address.)

`php.ini` in VirtualBox:

```ini
[xdebug]
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = 192.168.56.1
xdebug.client_port = 9003
```

VSCode `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "Listen for XDebug",
    "type": "php",
    "request": "launch",
    "port": 9003,
    "log": true,
    "pathMappings": {
        "/nginx": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
}
```

The following is the output from VSCode:

```
Listening on { address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 9003 }
<- launchResponse
Response { seq: 0, type: 'response', request_seq: 2, command: 'launch', success: true }
<- initializedEvent
InitializedEvent { seq: 0, type: 'event', event: 'initialized' }
-> setFunctionBreakpointsRequest
{ command: 'setFunctionBreakpoints',
  arguments: { breakpoints: [] },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 3 }
<- setFunctionBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 3,
  command: 'setFunctionBreakpoints',
  success: true,
  body: { breakpoints: [] } }
-> setExceptionBreakpointsRequest
{ command: 'setExceptionBreakpoints',
  arguments: { filters: [] },
  type: 'request',
  seq: 4 }
<- setExceptionBreakpointsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 4,
  command: 'setExceptionBreakpoints',
  success: true,
  body: { breakpoints: [] } }
-> configurationDoneRequest
{ command: 'configurationDone', type: 'request', seq: 5 }
<- configurationDoneResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 5,
  command: 'configurationDone',
  success: true }
-> threadsRequest
{ command: 'threads', type: 'request', seq: 6 }
<- threadsResponse
Response {
  seq: 0,
  type: 'response',
  request_seq: 6,
  command: 'threads',
  success: true,
  body: { threads: [] } }
```

I think that the network settings are probably incorrect... or perhaps sshfs is not suitable for this type of work?

Comment: Possibly related questions: [`is:q closed:no [vscode] sshfs`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+%5Bvscode%5D+sshfs)

Comment: The official [Xdebug PHP Debug VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xdebug.php-debug) extension has support for sshfs in vscode - but this is not what you are using here. The configuration looks ok, but what I am seeing is that you are actually using some other VSCode extension for Xdebug. Probably the one from Devsense. Try to disable that one and see if it works.
Also, I recommend VSCode Remote SSH if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like VS Code made a successful connection to VS Code here. But I do think you might need to tweak your path mappings.

The VS Code log does not tell you this, but the Xdebug one can.

You need to set `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` with `xdebug.log_level=11`, and in that log, Xdebug will show everything that it is trying to do, and see, including whether breakpoints could work or not.